# JAXB remove trailing spaces, or prompt of invalid document

Tags: xml, jaxb, xsd

So I have some JAXB annotated class, and an xml representing this class. When I unmarshal the xml doc to the class, all works fine, the problem is, I have some empty spaces, and I want JAXB to either remove them, or prompt me, that the document is wrong, according to the schema I set in the unmarshaller, so far I tried:

1. Create a custom type with the restriction: "xs:pattern value="\S.+\S"
2. Use "xs:normalizedString" as the type
3. Use "xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" " in a custom type

None of the above works. Any idea why? Is this expected behavior?

**Note: I don't want to use @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyAwesomeAdapter.class).**

**EDIT:**

I realize that the original question was about unmarshalling, and the code below is about marshalling, but they are complementary processes, pretty similar.

**The class:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

@XmlElement
private String name;

public Person() {

}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private static final class MyValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getMessage());
        return true;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, SAXException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();

    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("src/person.xsd"));
    marshaller.setSchema(schema);

    marshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());

    Person person = new Person();
    person.setName("Name ");
    marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
}
```

}

**The schema:**

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <xs:element name="person">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element type="xs:normalizedString" name="name"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><person><name>Name </name></person>
```

As you can see, there is no validation error, an the output contains a space.

**EDIT AFTER ACCEPTING ANSWER**
It seems like the pattern works correctly.

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <xs:simpleType name="NameType">
        <xs:restriction base='xs:string'>
          <xs:pattern value='\S.*\S'/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="person">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="name" type="NameType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, using jdk1.8.0_20.

For validation, you can use an XML Schema containing a facet:

```
<xs:element  name="name">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base='xs:normalizedString'>
      <xs:pattern value='\S.*\S'/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

You can set the handler (as in your code) or catch the exception that will be thrown:

```
event: [severity=FATAL_ERROR,message=cvc-type.3.1.3: The value 'Name  ' of 
element 'name' is not valid.,locator=[url=null,line=-1,column=-1,node=null,
object=generated.Person@7cca494b,field=null]]
```

It works for both marshalling and unmarshalling.

Comment: True it works. It does not have to be normalizedString, it can be string.

Comment: Certainly so. I thought it'd express your intention more clearly, so I left it in.

Answer (score 2):

### Starting from XML Schema

The schema type should be set to `xs:token`.  This will cause the corresponding property to be generated with `XmlAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)`.

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/CollapsedStringAdapter.html

### Starting from Java Classes

> What I want is to use my own JAXB annotated classes, no need for JAXB
>   to generate them for me.

You can leverage the existing `CollapsedStringAdapter` on your own property two have the whitespace stripped during the unmarshal.

```
@XmlAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
public String getYourProperty() {
    return yourProperty;
}
```

> I was hoping that the xsd schema that I set in the unmarshaller, would
>   help JAXB trim, or enforce my normalizedString, or whiteSpace
>   constraints.

I would expect a validation event to occur during the unmarshal if you specified a `Schema` on the `Unmarshaller`.  Can you try registering a `ValidationEventHandler` on the `Unmarshaller` to see if anything is thrown?  It may be occuring at a low enough severity that it doesn't stop the unmarshal.

Comment: Thank you sir. Just to make sure this is not a misunderstanding, perhaps I should have added some code, I already have the JAXB annotated classes. I know that JAXB can generate classes from a schema, but i don't want this, it seems like your answer targets this? What I want is to use my own JAXB annotated classes, no need for JAXB to generate them for me. I was hoping that the xsd schema that I set in the unmarshaller, would help JAXB trim, or enforce my normalizedString, or whiteSpace constraints. Is this a misconception?

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 - I have updated my answer to provide some additional information.

Comment: Hi again, and thanks again. The first proposition is to use the XmlAdapter, which works, I already knew that, see note in bold in original question (oq).

Regarding the validation handler, I forgot to mention in the oq that I already had a handler registered, unfortunately the handler is never triggered.

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 - I had seen the part in bold, but I was trying to point out the `CollapsedStringAdapter` that is part of the JAXB APIs.  I consider this to be different from an `XmlAdapter` you create yourself (i.e `MyAwesomeAdapter`).